# getting element values from an xml soap response when there is double xml tag

Tags: php, xml, soap

I HAVE THIS XML RESPONSE FROM A SOAP CALL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><loginResponse xmlns="http://wws.adomain.com/"><loginResult><xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"><xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="replay" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true"><xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xs:element name="replay"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema><diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"><DocumentElement xmlns=""><replay diffgr:id="replay1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><code>OK</code><description>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><token>e6d354f2-b284569e20-b2def8f3ef4a</token><nmDealer>SAP001 NAME</nmDealer><idRegDealer>8763</idRegDealer><idRegGrupo>-1</idRegGrupo><idRegPuntoVenta>-1</idRegPuntoVenta><idRegUsuario>35350731</idRegUsuario><idRegVendedor>-1</idRegVendedor><idRegZona>-1</idRegZona><dsTpUsuario>CLIENTES</dsTpUsuario><dsPais>PRODUCCION</dsPais><idioma>EN</idioma><idRegIdioma>9</idRegIdioma><isImputar>False</isImputar><moneda>€</moneda><tpUsuario>1</tpUsuario><idRegComisionVariableDealer>-1</idRegComisionVariableDealer><permitirComisionVariableDealer>1</permitirComisionVariableDealer><firstAccess>0</firstAccess><acceptedConditions>False</acceptedConditions><idRegInsured>-1</idRegInsured><idRegAuditor>-1</idRegAuditor></root></description></replay></DocumentElement></diffgr:diffgram></loginResult></loginResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

http://prntscr.com/9cfdwk

---

I want to be able to get the values of element (eg token) in the second xml tag (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`) Any prompt assistance will be appreciated.

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
$s = new soapclientw($wsdlfile);
if (empty($proxyhost))
{

}
else{
    $s->setHTTPProxy($proxyhost,$proxyport,$proxyusr,$proxypassword);
}
$result = $s->send($msg,'http://wws.domain.com/login',60);

$myXMLData = $s->responseData;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($myXMLData);

if ($xml === false) {
    echo "Failed loading XML: ";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "<br>", $error->message;
    }
} 
else{
    echo $xml->token;
}
```

Comment: can you post the actual xml rather than an image?

Comment: @RamRaider - Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Given your original, highly dubious xml, the following is a bit of a hack but it works..

```
    $strxml='
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <soap:Body>
                <loginResponse xmlns="http://wws.adomain.com/">
                    <loginResult>
                        <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                            <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="replay" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                        <xs:element name="replay">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                                    <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:choice>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:schema>
                        <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
                            <DocumentElement xmlns="">
                                <replay diffgr:id="replay1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                                    <code>OK</code>
                                    <description>
                                        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                                        <root>
                                            <token>e6d354f2-b284569e20-b2def8f3ef4a</token>
                                            <nmDealer>SAP001 NAME</nmDealer>
                                            <idRegDealer>8763</idRegDealer>
                                            <idRegGrupo>-1</idRegGrupo>
                                            <idRegPuntoVenta>-1</idRegPuntoVenta>
                                            <idRegUsuario>35350731</idRegUsuario>
                                            <idRegVendedor>-1</idRegVendedor>
                                            <idRegZona>-1</idRegZona>
                                            <dsTpUsuario>CLIENTES</dsTpUsuario>
                                            <dsPais>PRODUCCION</dsPais>
                                            <idioma>EN</idioma>
                                            <idRegIdioma>9</idRegIdioma>
                                            <isImputar>False</isImputar>
                                            <moneda>€</moneda>
                                            <tpUsuario>1</tpUsuario>
                                            <idRegComisionVariableDealer>-1</idRegComisionVariableDealer>
                                            <permitirComisionVariableDealer>1</permitirComisionVariableDealer>
                                            <firstAccess>0</firstAccess>
                                            <acceptedConditions>False</acceptedConditions>
                                            <idRegInsured>-1</idRegInsured>
                                            <idRegAuditor>-1</idRegAuditor>
                                        </root>
                                    </description>
                                </replay>
                            </DocumentElement>
                        </diffgr:diffgram>
                    </loginResult>
                </loginResponse>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>';


    $strxml=htmlentities( $strxml );
    $search=array( 
        htmlentities( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' ),
        htmlentities( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' )
    );
    $strxml=html_entity_decode( str_replace( $search, '', $strxml ) );

    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
    $dom->validateOnParse=false;
    $dom->standalone=true;
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace=true;
    $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
    $dom->substituteEntities=false;
    $dom->recover=true;
    $dom->formatOutput=false;
    $dom->loadXML( $strxml );
    libxml_clear_errors();

    $col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('root')->item(0);
    if( $col ){
        foreach( $col->childNodes as $node ) echo $node->tagName.' '.$node->nodeValue.BR;   
    }
    $dom=null;
```

Comment: Thanks RamRaider for your time. I quite agree that the soap xml response is dubious cos it's not properly formed. The answer you gave above still did not work cos the string output shows that the second xml tag "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" is not replaced.

Comment: It is very badly formed XML - the provider should be told. Did it help/work for you? If so, accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I was able to figure it out myself.
Here is the code that worked for me:

```
$myXMLData = strip_tags($s->responseData);
$temp = explode("OK", $myXMLData);
$myXMLData = $temp[1];
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(htmlspecialchars_decode($myXMLData));
```

I stripped off all the soap tags, living me with the final xml data but with a leading 'OK' which I removed by explode().  Replacing the 'OK' with an empty string would have also worked.